# Why am I getting a 400 bad request error when submitting a form that I added inputs to?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-status-code-400, bad-request

**Background:** I have a node/express based web application that is basically a rating/database site for campgrounds.  You can view the current working version here: https://radiant-eyrie-76078.herokuapp.com and the github here: https://github.com/HashSlingSlash/YelpCamp.  I've just completed attempting to add user profiles by updating the signup form to include more information and adding a show page for each user.  Now whenever I click the signup button (or send a post request to /register using postman) I get a 400 Bad Request error.   If I then go to the home page I can sign in as the user that I attempted to register so the user is getting registered despite the bad request error.  I have tried clearing my cache and browsing history and using other browsers, but it still won't work.  I even tried removing all the changes I made to the form to make it just username and password again and it still did not work. I have tried fixing this and debugging for hours and I cannot understand what could be happening.

**Here is my register page:**

```
<%- include("./partials/header") %>
 
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="login-header">Sign Up</h1>
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newUser[username]" placeholder="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newUser[firstName]" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newUser[lastName]" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="newUser[email]" placeholder="email@mail.com" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newUser[avatar]" placeholder="avatar url" id="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="admin">Admin Key (Enter admin key here if you've been given one)</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="adminKey" placeholder="********" id="admin">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
 
<%- include("./partials/footer") %>
```

**Here are my index routes:**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../models/user");
const Campground = require("../models/campground");
 
//root route
router.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.render("landing");
});
 
//show register form
router.get("/register", (req, res) =>{
    res.render("register", {page: "register"});
});
 
//handle sign up logic
router.post("/register", (req, res) =>{
    const newUser = new User(req.body.newUser);
    if(req.body.adminKey === "secret"){
        newUser.isAdmin = true;
    }
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user) =>{
        if(err){
            return res.render("register", {"error": err.message});
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () =>{
            req.flash("success", "Welcome to YelpCamp " + user.username);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        });
    });
});
 
//login form
router.get("/login", (req, res) =>{
    res.render("login", {page: "login"});
});
 
//login logic
router.post("/login", 
passport.authenticate("local", 
{
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}), (req, res) =>{
    req.flash("success", "Welcome back " + req.user.username);
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
});
 
//logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res) =>{
    req.logOut();
    req.flash("success", "Logged you out!");
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
});
 
//user profile
router.get("/user/:id", (req, res) =>{
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundUser) =>{
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        Campground.find().where("author.id").equals(foundUser._id).exec((err, campgrounds) =>{
            if(err){
                req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                return res.redirect("back");
            }
            res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser, campgrounds: campgrounds});  
        });
    });
});
 
 
module.exports = router;
```

Here is my User schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    avatar: String,
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I've tried fixing this for hours and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you show your register route?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti It's the code block under "handle signup logic"  The one that starts with router.post("/register"

Comment: Can you show your User.register method in the schema?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I've edited the question to include the User schema.  That method is coming from passport local mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. I had to change the name attribute on the form inputs to just username, password, email, etc. I believe passport local mongoose expects to receive the data according to those key value pairs specifically, although I am unsure as to the exact reason why this is necessary since I end up giving the data as an object either way. In case anyone wants to see it here is my updated and working code:

**Register form:**

```
<%- include("./partials/header") %>

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="login-header">Sign Up</h1>
    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@mail.com" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="avatar" placeholder="avatar url" id="avatar">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="admin">Admin Key (Enter admin key here if you've been given one)</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="adminKey" placeholder="********" id="admin">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
    </div>
</div>

<%- include("./partials/footer") %>
```

**Route:**

```
//handle sign up logic
router.post("/register", (req, res) =>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar: req.body.avatar
    });
    if(req.body.adminKey === "secret"){
        newUser.isAdmin = true;
    }
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user) =>{
        if(err){
            return res.render("register", {"error": err.message});
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () =>{
            req.flash("success", "Welcome to YelpCamp " + user.username);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        });
    });
});
```